# What kinds of resources are accessible through javascript on browser environment?

Tags: javascript, browser, resources, frontend

As far as i know there are so many restrictions, for security reasons, on the javascript on browser environment, like file I/O (even that are some sand boxes that make it possible), book marks removal. I would like to list what resources are accessible directly through javascript, and what resources aren't accessible?
Somebody have this list easy?

Some examples of resources are: camera, microphone, file system, browser features (bookmarks, history, extensions) etc.

Comment: if possible, put a link to a tutorial/explanation on the browser resource.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions there is about extension app permissions it may related(geolocation,camera etc.). You marked a good point, this will be good resource for client-side javascripting.